# Create nested dictionary with csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to create several nested dictionaries out of a csv data file. I am not sure how to properly format the dictionary.

Here is the csv file

```
1,Afghanistan,MENA,20-24,Female,Urban,6.786986809,442.6952889,1.53%
```

I need to pull `country`, `region`, `age_group`, `gender`, `geographic_area`, `diabetes` and `population` as strings/floats.

The following is my code:

```
diabetes_data = []
D = {}
fp.readline()
for line in fp:
  line = line.split(',')
  country = str(line[1])
  region = str(line[2])
  age_group = str(line[3])
  gender = str(line[4])
  geographic_area = str(line[5])
  diabetes = int(float(line[6])*1000)
  population = int(float(line[7])*1000)

  tup = (gender, geographic_area, diabetes, population)
  diabetes_data.append(tup)

  D = {country: region: age_group: diabetes_data }
```

I am trying to return the finished dictionary D that nests a dictionary of the country inside another dictionary of region inside another one of age group that has the values of the tuple diabetes_data.

I am unsure of how to preceded, I am currently using a single for loop and am not sure if I need to have multiple.

The final dictionary should look like the following:

```
{'MENA': {'Afghanistan': {'20-24': [('Female', 'Urban', 6786,
442695), ('Male', 'Urban', 2699, 474429)], '35-39': [('Female',
'Urban', 17834, 237228), ('Male', 'Urban', 14852, 262910)], '50-54':
[('Female', 'Urban', 21715, 117219), ('Male', 'Urban', 23055,
126786)], ... and so on
```

Comment: The `D` dictionary isn't a valid python dict.

Comment: What would be the correct way to set it up then? I realise there are errors and some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look into the `csv` library, which can help with parsing the string in the first place. Then you could simply work with the arguments you get back from it, which might be easier.

Comment: I am not allowed the use csv commands as this is a project for school. I can only use basic loops and .split

Comment: What does the final dictionary need to look like? You should include that in your question.

Comment: Here, I updated it with the proper final dictionary output

Answer (score 0):

```
D[region] = {country: {age_group: diabetes_data}}
```

This creates a dictionary inside a dictionary inside another dictionary with the value as a tuple.

Comment: if you are happy with your own answer check it to lower the number of open questions on stackoverflow. thank you